# Changing width filter inputbox primefaces datatable

Tags: css, filter, datatable, width, primefaces

Hi how do i apply the ccs style for the filter inputbox in a primefaces datatable, trying to use filterstyle this way:

```
 <p:column styleClass="placaColumna" filterStyle="width=16px" headerText="Placa" filterBy="# 
 {bandeja.placa}"><h:outputText value ="#{bandeja.placa}"/></p:column>
```

thanks :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your inline style CSS syntax is incorrect.  It should be like this.

```
filterStyle="width: 16px;"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an CSS class with the option filterStyleClass

Don't forget to use !important in your css class

```
filterStyleClass="cssClass"

.cssClass{width: 16px !important}
```