# resize filter input in p:dataTable

Tags: input, primefaces, datatable

How can I resize input text in primefaces data table

```
<p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{bb.ID}" filterBy="#{bb.ID}" filterMatchMode="contains"
    style="text-align: center;" styleClass="headerText">
    <p:outputLabel styleClass="OutputLabel" value="#{bb.ID}" />
</p:column>
```

[image: Table image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't vote for duplicates yet the answer is simple...

Duplicate of: [Changing width filter inputbox primefaces datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929365/changing-width-filter-inputbox-primefaces-datatable)

Just use a filterStyle property like filterStyle="width:20px".

```
<p:column headerText="ID" 
          sortBy="#{bb.ID}" 
          filterBy="#{bb.ID}"
          filterStyle="width: 20px" 
          filterMatchMode="contains"  
          style="text-align: center;" 
          styleClass="headerText">
```